# Why does react router 4 not redirect?

Tags: react-router-v4

I am using `react-router-dom` and I am not redirecting.  Here are the routes:

```
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Switch>
  <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/drills/list" component={Drills.List} />
  <Route path="/drills/list/:filter" component={Drills.List} />

  <Redirect from="/drills" to="/drills/list/active" />

  <Redirect to="/error" />
</Switch>
```

Also, here is my initial `Router` config:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

<Provider store={getStore()}>
    <Router routes={routes} />
</Provider>
```

All of the `Route`'s work without an issue, but when it the url is one of the `Redirect`'s, nothing happens.  For example, if `http://localhost:3000/foo`, the url doesn't change and the parent page loads.  Any ideas?